# Eye blink detection

Tags: c++, algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision

The main purpose for my system (in realtime HD videos) is after detecting the face we can easily detect the eyes, my system need to know how many times that the person close his eyes per minute for example, and tracking his eyes also, any ideas to implement that?

Maybe something like this video, but the in the real-live video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JL3Gbb9aY0c

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8m4ovTZSYA

Answer (score 2):

If you are detecting the eyes, then you have some indicator value that describes a quality of detection (for example, correlation coefficient if template is used or intensity of Hough transform peak if circles are searched for).

You can carry out some experiments and plot this value  to find how much it declines when blinking occurs.
So situation with transition *high value-low(below some level)-high* like `10-10-11-9-11-10-5-2-6-11-10` may indicate blink case.

Answer (score 0):

This python code should help you start-off with eye blink detection using OpenCV and Python. The code implementation requires that you download the [landmarks](https://github.com/AKSHAYUBHAT/TensorFace/blob/master/openface/models/dlib/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat) file and install **dlib** using this command:

```
pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/da/06/bd3e241c4eb0a662914b3b4875fc52dd176a9db0d4a2c915ac2ad8800e9e/dlib-19.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

Now, your good to go! You can place the **landmarks(.dat)** file in the same folder as the code below and run the script below in terminal

```
import numpy as np
import dlib
from math import hypot
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)#camera port 0


detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")

def midpoint(p1,p2):
    return int((p1.x + p2.x)/2),int((p1.y + p2.y)/2)

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

def get_blinking_ratio(eye_points, facial_landmarks):
    left_point = (facial_landmarks.part(eye_points[0]).x, facial_landmarks.part(eye_points[0]).y)
    right_point = (facial_landmarks.part(eye_points[3]).x, facial_landmarks.part(eye_points[3]).y)
    hor_line = cv2.line(frame, left_point, right_point,(0,255,0), 1)

    center_top = midpoint(facial_landmarks.part(eye_points[1]), facial_landmarks.part(eye_points[2]))
    center_bottom = midpoint(facial_landmarks.part(eye_points[5]), facial_landmarks.part(eye_points[4]))
    ver_line = cv2.line(frame, center_top, center_bottom,(0,255,0), 1)

    #length of the line
    hor_line_length = hypot((left_point[0] - right_point[0]), (left_point[1] - right_point[1]))
    ver_line_length = hypot((center_top[0] - center_bottom[0]), (center_top[1] - center_bottom[1]))
    ratio = hor_line_length/ ver_line_length, ver_line_length
    return ratio

blink = 1
TOTAL = 0
thres = 5.1
while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)#for gray images(lightweight)
    faces = detector(gray)
    for face in faces:
        #x, y = face.left(), face.top()
        #x1, y1 = face.right(), face.bottom()
        #cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x1,y1), (0,255,0), 3 )# green box, thickness of box
        landmarks = predictor(gray, face)
        left_eye_ratio,_ = get_blinking_ratio([36,37,38,39,40,41], landmarks)
        right_eye_ratio, myVerti = get_blinking_ratio([42,43,44,45,46,47], landmarks)
        blinking_ratio = (left_eye_ratio+right_eye_ratio)/2
        personal_threshold = 0.67 * myVerti #0.67 is just the best constant I found with experimentation
        cv2.putText(frame, "left ratio: {:.2f}".format(left_eye_ratio), (300, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(frame, "right ratio: {:.2f}".format(right_eye_ratio), (500, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        if (left_eye_ratio>personal_threshold or right_eye_ratio>personal_threshold) and blink == 1:
            TOTAL += 1
            time.sleep(0.3)#average persons blinking time
        if (left_eye_ratio>personal_threshold or right_eye_ratio>personal_threshold):
            blink = 0
        else:
            blink = 1

        cv2.putText(frame, "Blinks: {}".format(TOTAL), (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(5)
    if key == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindow()
```

It detects and counts blinks for any person with any size of eye. Unfortunately, I am having trouble with detecting eye blinks for people with spectacles.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ear > EYE_AR_THRESH:
        COUNTER += 1        
else:           
    if COUNTER >= EYE_AR_CONSEC_FRAMES:
        TOTAL = TOTAL+1
        print(TOTAL)
        # COUNTER = 0
        # print(COUNTER)
    cv2.putText(img, "Blinks: {}".format(TOTAL), (10, 30),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.putText(img, "EAR: {:.2f}".format(ear), (300, 30),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow('detect eyes blink', img)

if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```